# Compilation error about a union field in another union

Tags: c, unions

Consider below code, I have written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

union myAccess {
    uint16_t access16;
    struct {
        uint8_t lo;
        uint8_t hi;
        } access8;
    };

union myByte{
    uint8_t  BYTE;
    struct {
        unsigned BIT0:1;
        unsigned BIT1:1;
        unsigned BIT2:1;
        unsigned BIT3:1;
        unsigned BIT4:1;
        unsigned BIT5:1;
        unsigned BIT6:1;
        unsigned BIT7:1;
        }BIT;
    };

int main()
{

   union myAccess U;
   U.access8.lo=0xF1;
   U.access8.hi=0x55;
   printf("%x\n",U);


   union myByte B;
   B.BYTE=0;
   B.BIT.BIT4=1;
   printf("%x\n",B);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Gaurav@Gaurav-PC /cygdrive/d
$ ./LSI
2255f1
61279210
```

Now when I modify my code as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

union myAccess {
    uint16_t access16;
    struct {
        uint8_t lo;
        union myByte hi;//here
        } access8;
    };

union myByte{
    uint8_t  BYTE;
    struct {
        unsigned BIT0:1;
        unsigned BIT1:1;
        unsigned BIT2:1;
        unsigned BIT3:1;
        unsigned BIT4:1;
        unsigned BIT5:1;
        unsigned BIT6:1;
        unsigned BIT7:1;
        }BIT;
    };

int main()
{

    union myAccess U;
    U.access8.lo=0xF1;
    U.access8.hi.BYTE=0x55;
    printf("%x\n",U);
    return 0;
}
```

It is showing compilation error at here

```
Gaurav@Gaurav-PC /cygdrive/d
$ gcc -Wall LSI.c -o LSI
LSI.c:8: error: field `hi' has incomplete type
LSI.c: In function `main':
LSI.c:33: warning: unsigned int format, myAccess arg (arg 2)
LSI.c:33: warning: unsigned int format, myAccess arg (arg 2)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second example, when `union myAccess` is defined, its field `hi` has type `union myByte`, but that type is not defined yet. You need to put the definition of `union myByte` before `union myAccess`.

Comment: Ahh silly me.. got it.. But one more thing I tried prototype `union myByte` just after `#include <stdint.h>` , but still got same error .. why so?

Comment: @GauravK Does your code now look like this: http://ideone.com/ttkZRB ? Compiles fine by me.

Comment: Yes that works fine.. What I am saying .. what is wrong with 
`#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

union myByte;

   union myAccess {
       uint16_t access16;
       struct {
           uint8_t lo;
           union myByte hi;//here
           } access8;
    };
union myByte{
    uint8_t  BYTE;
    struct {
        .....
        }BIT;

    };` I have added a prototype for union;

Comment: @GauravK Forward declaration won't work because you need a complete type here, you are using the `union` itself, not a pointer to it.

Comment: With that code .. It compiles successfully but output is not correct .. `union myAccess U;U.access8.lo=0xF1;U.access8.hi.BYTE=0x55;printf("%x\n",U);` I am getting o/p `$ ./LSI
612792f1
` .. it should have been `612755f1`.. what is wrong?

Comment: @GauravK That's a different question, try debug it yourself first.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the union `myByte` before you reference it within your other `myAccess` union.

[Working example here.](http://ideone.com/GRXJE7)

Comment: I tried prototype `union myByte` just after `#include <stdint.h>` , but still got same error .. why so?

Comment: I added a link that compiles successfully and runs fine. Double check your code.

Comment: Yes it works.. I am saying .. instead of first defining `myByte` and then `myAccess`.. what if I just add a prototype at the start of code `#include <stdint.> union myByte;`.. it does not compile

Comment: That is a forward declaration for the type. You cannot use that type as a member of a class/struct/union. You can use a reference or pointer to a forward declared type as a member variable. 
`struct Foo; // forward declaration`
`struct Widget { Foo* goodFoo; Foo  errorFoo; };`

Answer (score 0):

You are not declaring the `union myByte` before using it in as a member of the `struct` in `myAccess`. The compiler needs to know what is the type `myByte` before it can be used.

Trying to use `myByte` as type in `myAccess` is logically equivalent as trying to use a variable before declaring it:

```
int main(void) {
   int a = 1, b = 1;
   c = a + b;
   int c;
   return c;
}
```

This will throw a compilation error claiming that `c` is undeclared.